# Diagonal center of a 4 points polynome

Tags: javascript, math

I am trying to find (diagonal) center of a 4 points polynome:

[image]

I thought it is as simple as this:

[image]

But it seems it is not... So how to callculate/find center x/y of it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection#Given_two_points_on_each_line

Comment: Could you provide a working example please, I am aware of that very complex equation, thank you!

Comment: Use the explicit formula just below the "determinant notation" ([here](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/c51a9b486a6ef5a7a08b92d75e71a07888034a9a)); it is no different to the equivalent code.

Comment: I am following your suggest: https://jsfiddle.net/akkara/gf5evhqd/17/ but looks like something wrong, y equals a negative value

Comment: Great! Please put your response as an answer, then I want to accept it as solution, Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on from the comments, using the formula from [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection#Given_two_points_on_each_line):

[image]

... you can compute the intersection point of the diagonals, assuming that the polygon is convex (i.e. the diagonals always intersect).

> Note that the point indices are *different* to those of your polygon: the diagonals are between points `1 – 3` and `2 – 4` respectively, whereas your polygon points are ordered `1 - 2 - 3 - 4`.

Working snippet:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

function line (ax,ay,bx,by) {
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.moveTo(ax,ay);
 ctx.lineTo(bx,by);
 ctx.stroke();
}

var x1 = 100 ;
var y1 = 100 ;
var x2 = 110 ;
var y2 = 320 ;
var x3 = 400 ;
var y3 = 200 ;
var x4 = 300 ;
var y4 = 100 ;

// Lines
line(x1,y1,x2,y2) ;
line(x2,y2,x3,y3) ;
line(x3,y3,x4,y4) ;
line(x1,y1,x4,y4) ;

// Diagonals
line(x1,y1,x3,y3) ;
line(x4,y4,x2,y2) ;

var div = (x1-x3)*(y2-y4)-(y1-y3)*(x2-x4) ;
var divx = (x1*y3-y1*x3)*(x2-x4) - (x1-x3)*(x2*y4-y2*x4) ;
var divy = (x1*y3-y1*x3)*(y2-y4) - (y1-y3)*(x2*y4-y2*x4) ;

var x = divx/div ;
var y = divy/div ;

$("#x").val(x) ;
$("#y").val(y) ;

// Center
line(x,y-10,x,y+10) ;
line(x-10,y,x+10,y) ;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="x" disabled /> 
<input id="y" disabled />
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="600" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about **gravitational center** then it will be as following:

```
G = (A + B + C + D) / 4

means:
xG = (xA + xB + xC + xD) / 4
yG = (yA + yB + yC + yD) / 4
```

You can see here: [Geometric centroid](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeometricCentroid.html)

[image: formular]

Comment: 1) OP did not mention the need to calculate the center of mass. 2) Even if they did, it would require clarification on whether the shape is solid or composed of 4 point masses (which your formula assumes). 3) The diagram on the Wolfram Alpha page clearly shows that the resultant point is not equal to OP's desired point.